# QListView - mixed drag mode

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I have a QListView with the ViewMode set to IconMode. I would like to achieve the following DnD behavior:

- If a list view item is dragged inside the view, only the items position in the view is changed. This is the same as setting DragDropMode equal to InternalMove.
- If a list item is moved out of the view, it can be copied to another external view. In this case, DragDropMode is equal to DragOnly.

How do I mix the two modes in such a way that both behaviors are supported by the view?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this by overriding the [dropEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractitemview.html#dropEvent) of your view like this:

```
void MyListView::dropEvent( QDropEvent* e )
{
    if( e->source() != this )
    {
        // something comes from the outside
        // what to do? return?
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // event comes from the view itself, let's do some stuff
        // for example call the base class default event
        QAbstractItemView::dropEvent(e);
    }
}
```

I guess the correct flag would be `QAbstractItemView::DragDrop` to do this.